# Why is Ok() method returning with text/plain media type instead of application/json?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-webapi

The documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-3.1) says that results returned with the `Ok()` method are formatted as json by default. I assumed this would also mean it  returns as application/json but using fiddler I am seeing that this is not the case for me.

The thing is, I am returning a string that is already formatted as json. Is that the problem? How do I cause it to return with an application/json media type?

EDIT:

I just read that Ok() does return text/plain instead of application/json when it's provided a string, which makes it unusable for returning raw json. The answer seems to be to return `Content(rawJson, "application/json")`.

That does fix my problem, but now I'm wondering if there is a way I can just globally set the media type to always be json? If not I  suppose I  could just  create a base controller class with a method to  handle it.

Comment: Have you set the `Accept` header in fiddle?

Comment: @Progman No, but see my edit.

Answer (score 5):

You can add a global filter. In your `Startup.cs` `ConfigureServices` method, locate `services.AddControllers();` and add as follows:

```
services.AddControllers(config => config.Filters.Add(new ProducesAttribute("application/json")));
```

This now alleviates the need to add it at the controller level.